# Spring file upload by ajax

Tags: jquery, spring

From yeasterday i'm trying to upload file by ajax to my `Spring` application. This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal )
{   
    if( principal != null ) {

    } 

    return "";
}
```

form in html code:

```
<form id="uploadImageForm" 
          name="uploadImageForm" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class='dialog' style='width:200px;'>
            <div class='green_button' id='files' name='files'>
                <div class='green_button_text' id="add_image">
                    wybierz zdjęcie
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInputHidden" style="display:none"/>
            </div>
<script>
    $("#add_image").click(function(){
        $("input[id='fileInputHidden']").click();
    });
</script>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Script to send file by ajax:

```
 document.getElementById('fileInputHidden').addEventListener('change', this.onFileChange, false);
},

this.onFileChange   = function( evt ) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    if( !file != null ) {
        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            $( document.forms['uploadImageForm'] ).ajaxUpload( {
                url: CONTEXT_URL + "/upload",
                method: "POST",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#accept").css("opacity","1");
                    $("#accept").click(function(){
                        $("#ac").css("display","none");
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            alert("Wybrany plik nie jest zdjęciem!");
        }
    }
```

in dispacher-servlet.xml added `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean. 
when jquery send ajax post request, get Internal error (500) and my stack looks like:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/jadenazlot] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
```

I tryied to change @RequestParam annotation to

```
String uploadFileHandler(@ModelAttribute("uploadImageForm") UploadedFile file ) {/*...*/}
```

Uploaded file is my own class with getter and setter but, then i'm get NullPointerExcepotions in `file.getFile()`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your multipartresolver definition?

Comment: i found solution, in MultipartResolver i didn't set maxUploadSize...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MultipartResolver have to set maxUploadSize.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot for this post. You saved my few hours.